# Why does lodash `_.all([true, true, true], true);` return `false`?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I check if all elements of an array are truthy or falsey.

Since the following doesn't seem to do it:
`_.all([true, true, true], true);`

it returns: `false`?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#every suggests you are not using this function correctly (to start off, it's no longer `_.all`)

Comment: `_.every([true, true, true]);` Should work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should re-read the `_.every(collection, [predicate=_.identity])` [api doc](https://lodash.com/docs/#every) of lodash. The issue with your code is the second param you are passing. Remove it and it works

```
> _.every([true, 'foo', 1])
true
> _.every([true, 'foo', 1, 0])
false
```